# Disable MongoDB logging with flag on MsiExecWithFlags?

Tags: mongodb, inno-setup

I'm installing MongoDB using Inno Setup. Related line of my setup.iss file:

```
  MsiExecWithFlags('{app}\dependencies\mongodb.msi', 'SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0" ADDLOCAL="ServerService"', 'MongoDB Community Server');
```

I need to completely disable MongoDB logging, and I've found that in order to achieve that I need to set systemLog.quiet = true, but it's not working:

```
  MsiExecWithFlags('{app}\dependencies\mongodb.msi', 'SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0" ADDLOCAL="ServerService" systemLog.quiet="true"', 'MongoDB Community Server');
```

Is disabling MongoDB logging even possible to set, as a flag in parameter of installer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the .msi file. The MongoDB server is a single .exe (`mongod.exe`), you don't need anything else apart from a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/). Download the .zip, extract it and copy the .exe with your .iss file.

After copy run `mongod.exe --config <the config file you created> --install` to create the service.

See my repository https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick as example. It should be no challenge to extract the ISS commands from the batch file, I created there.

Comment: Hello, thanks for Your comment, i've found Your gh helpful. But anyway, i didn't saw options 'SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0" ADDLOCAL="ServerService" for cfg file, nor i have found any other person's cfg file with that parameter, and also Mongo docs for cfg files are not covering these parameters.